# Update record in test db for rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a record `record` with attribute `attribute` that I want to set to `{}`, so I've tried

```
// spec file
record.update_attribute(attribute: {})
record.attribute = {}

// factorybot file
trait :update_attr do
 attribute {{}}
end
```

But neither has worked when I look for it thru my spec in a script that uses

```
Record.where(attribute: {})
```

Because it defaults to having its attribute set. When I print out the record in my spec file, it has the correct attribute, but when I print it out in the script, it has the wrong attribute. I'm not sure where this is being set because I don't see anything in the factory file, but would love to learn how to change the attribute.

Below is example code:

spec file

```
require 'rails_helper'
require_relative Rails.root.join('script/test.rb')

RSpec.describe FixRecord do
  let(:record) { FactoryBot.create(:record) }

  subject { described_class.call }

  describe 'class#call' do
    before do
      preset.configurations = {}
    end
    it 'fixes record' do
      # this puts will show the record with x id and attribute to be {}
      puts 'record', preset.attribute, record.id
      subject
      expect(preset.attribute).to eq({foo:'bar'})
    end
  end
end
```

**script file**

```
  class ResetError < StandardError; end

  BATCH_SIZE = 1000

  def self.call
    new.call
  end

  def call
    # calling Record.find(x).attribute here return record with filled attribute instead of {}
    binding.pry

    Record.where("attribute=?", "{}") do |record|
      record.update(attribute: {foo: 'bar'})
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Show actual code: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: @smathy I've included code example

Comment: what is the type of the column that you are trying to set to {}

Comment: Frankly all this code is straight up bizarre. Why should an exception class be updating your database?!! Maybe just tell us what it is that you're actually trying to achieve here on a higher level so that we can actually help you?

Comment: I don't really understand what you think `Record.where(attribute: {})` or `Record.where("attribute=?", "{}")` will actually do either unless the column is a text column containing serialized JSON. To check for an empty JSON object in actual JSON columns you need to use the database specific functions.